# relation of table with multiple roles

Tags: database, database-design, openoffice-base

stupid question I guess...

I want to realize a simple database with shipping orders. Order can be sent and received by customers.

An order could have a date and two foreign keys relative to shipper and sender.

Something like this

```
Orders(ID,Date,id_sender,id_receiver)
```

A simplified customer table would be

```
Customers(ID,name, surname,city)
```

I noticed that I can't create two Customers/Orders relationships where one is relative to the foreign key id_sender and the other to id_receiver. I just tried with the OpenOffice DBMS and I get an error when trying to establish the second relationship because a relationship between Customers and Orders already exists.

```
ID in statement [ALTER TABLE "Orders" ADD FOREIGN KEY("id_sender","id_receiver") REFERENCES "Customers"("ID","ID")
```

How should I solve this ??? Thanks and sorry if that's a maybe stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is trying to create one composite foreign key with two columns, is_sender and id_receiver, both referencing the same column, id on Customers. That's probably not what you want. Instead, you might try to define two separate constraints:

```
alter table Orders add foreign key (id_sender) references Customers (id);
alter table Orders add foreign key (id_receiver) references Customers (id);
```